# foreach PHP delete against mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach, sql-delete

What I have so far is (what I believe to be) a working loop, iterating through and getting the correct id's (confirmed by var_dump), yet my sql query is not picking up the id's as the DELETE keys.  Essentially, SQL query is deleting where the id = the current id value of the array iteration. Uses multi checkbox. var dump is confirming that the id matches the upload id, however I can't get any deletion to take place.  Here's the code:

```
       function submit_delete() {
      if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox'])) { //Check to see if a     delete command has been submitted.
    //This will dump your checkbox array to your screen if the submit works.
    //You can manually check to see if you're getting the correct array with values
   // var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);//Comment this out once it's working.
    $id_array = $_POST['checkbox'];
    //var_dump($id_array);
    deleteUploads($id_array);

  }
  else {
    echo "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";//var_dump($_POST['checkbox']);
  }
}


function deleteUploads ($id_array) {
  if (count($id_array) <= 0) {   echo "Error: No deletes in id_array!"; echo 'wtf'; }
  //return; }//bail if its empty
  require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); //Connect to the db

  $delete_success = false; var_dump($delete_success);
  foreach ($id_array as $id) { var_dump($id);
    $remove = "DELETE FROM upload WHERE upload_id= $id";//AND `owner_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $remove); // Run the query
    //
    ////$mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if ($result) { $delete_success = true; var_dump($delete_success);}
    mysqli_close($dbc);
  }



  if($delete_success == true) { echo 'done';
    header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
  } else {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error();
  }
}


//Test deleteUploads (remove once you know the function is working)
//$test_ids = array();
//$test_ids[] = 5;//make sure this id is in the db
//$test_ids[] = 7;//this one too
submit_delete();
//deleteUploads($id_array);//should remove ids 10 and 9//

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop produce at least one deletion before it shuts off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `mysqli_close($dbc);` statement from your `deleteUploads()` function.
I also agree yhou should work on accepting peoples answers. You've asked 9 questions and you haven't accepted one of the 13 answers. This isn't really playing fair.

**Edit**
I've quickly run through your script and moved it around a bit.
Does this provide any useful information?

```
<?
$msgs[] = 'Log: Started';
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

function submit_delete()
{
    global $msgs;
    if(!is_null($_POST['delete']) && !is_null($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        $msgs[] = "Log: submit_delete called with valid checkbox delete.";
        $id_array = $_POST['checkbox'];
        deleteUploads($id_array);
    }else{
        $msgs[] = "Error: submit_delete called without valid checkbox delete.";
    }
}

function deleteUploads ($id_array)
{
    global $msgs;
    if (count($id_array) <= 0)
    {
        $msgs[] = "Error: No deletes in id_array!";
    }else{
        $msgs[] = "Log: Deletes in id_array!";
    }

    $delete_success = false;
    foreach ($id_array as $id)
    {
        $msgs[] = "Log: Processing id: ".$id;
        $remove = "DELETE FROM upload WHERE upload_id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $remove);
        if ($result)
        {
            $msgs[] = 'Log: delete success = true';
            header('Location: newwriter_profile.php');
        }else{
            $msgs[] = 'Error: '.mysqli_error();
        }
    }
}

submit_delete();

if(!@mysqli_close($dbc))
{
    $msgs[] = 'Error: mysqli_close failed';
}
echo implode('<br>',$msgs);
?>
```

Comment: Also, shouldn't the loop run the DELETE at least one time - prior to closing the connection?

Comment: I just confirmed that this does not solve the problem, no DELETE occurs after removing mysqli_close